# Requested template has been denied access

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, coldfusion-10

Recently, a migration from CF8 to CF10 has caused some issues.  Both environments are sandboxed.  The developers are moving their CF8 production code to the CF10 development environment to test and refine before moving to CF10 production.

The CF8 data areas were hosted locally on the server.  The CF10 data areas are hosted on a NAS device.  This is the code that is referenced in the error:

```
    <cfinvoke component="popup/ListComponent" method="diaplayDivNavigazione" form=search_files page=#JavaCast("int",page)# recordCount=#fatFileData.RecordCount# maxRows=#maxrow# field=page>
```

The error is produced in the CF10 dev environment but performs as expected in the CF8 production environment.  The error is:

```
Security: The requested template has been denied access to C:/ColdFusion10/cfusion3/gateway/cfc.
```

The following is the internal exception message: access denied (java.io.FilePermission C:/ColdFusion10/cfusion3/gateway/cfc read)

The error makes me think the app cannot read C:/Coldfusion10/cfusion3/gateway/cfc.  This mapping is present in the CF Admin for the overall server.  Must it be specified in the individual sandbox as well?  As far as the sandbox access, I added R/W/E/D access to the "popup" directory listed in the code using "FULLPATH\popup\" and "FULLPATH\popup-"

I cannot access the page to test and must wait for the developer.  Is there anything else that I could add, modify or enable to resolve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this a linux or windows server?

Comment: My apologies. This is a Windows 2008 R2 Server running IIS 7.5

Comment: Sounds like a folder permission issue. Can you check to see if ColdFusion is a user for the Coldfusion10 folder?

Comment: The Coldfusion runtime user is present and has full control of the Coldfusion10 folder.

Comment: The error that is being reported - _access denied (java.io.FilePermission_ - is coming from the sandbox security. If I understand correctly, you have a mapping named "popup" that you are using in the code. The sandbox however requires physical paths. It looks like you added a sandbox entry for the "popup" mapping. That won't work. Add an entry for the physical path instead. And by the way, from the error, that piece of code only requires READ access. And you are also missing a trailing slash "\" in your sandbox setting _"FULLPATH\popup-" should be ""FULLPATH\popup\-""_

Comment: @Miguel-F, thank you.  The trailing slash was my mistake.  Are you suggesting to add this path within the application's own sandbox on the Files/Dirs tab?

I have added  \\FULLPATH\popup\ and  \\FULLPATH\popup\- both with read only permissions.

Comment: So after adding those entries are you still getting the error?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  The full file path is listed.

Unfortunately, I am only the administrator of the server and haven't access to the application with the error.  I will unfortunately have to wait for the developer's confirmation.

Comment: Just to be clear, it wants physical path like "C:\path\to\your\template\".  Not "\\FULLPATH\".

Comment: Correct, I understand that it wants the full path.  I'd rather not publish the full path so I am using FULLPATH to denote this.  Would this make any difference if the files being referenced are on a NAS device instead of locally on the server?

Comment: I don't think so. As far as the server knows that is a local drive. Right?  Obviously users privs will also be involved here but I think you already clarified that the ColdFusion user has rights.

Comment: Correct.  The Coldfusion user has access to the data area on the NAS device and the Coldfusion instance on the server.

Comment: Does the server's user have user rights to the NAS?

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and post my comments as an answer so that they are easier to find for people. After you have tested please come back here and either accept the answer or add more details so we can help you further.  And by they way, you don't need access to the code to test this but you do need access to the page. If you can browse to the page throwing the error that will test it. The sandbox settings do not require a restart.

Comment: @CoryFail, good point.  After double checking, the server user does have access to the NAS.

Answer (score 2):

*Promoted from the comments*

The error that is being reported - *access denied (java.io.FilePermission ...* - is coming from the sandbox security. If I understand correctly, you have a mapping named "popup" that you are using in the code. The sandbox however requires physical paths. I do not see the folder "popup" in the error message you provided. It looks like you added a sandbox entry for the "popup" mapping. That won't work. Add an entry for the physical path instead.

And by the way, from the error, that piece of code only requires READ access.
And you are also missing a trailing slash "\" in your sandbox setting.

```
C:\FULLPATH\popup-
```

should be

```
C:\FULLPATH\The_Real_Folder_Name\-
```

and you also need the other (without the hyphen)

```
C:\FULLPATH\The_Real_Folder_Name\
```

You don't need access to the code to test this but you do need access to the page. If you can browse to the page that is throwing the error then that will test it. Modifying the sandbox settings does not require a restart.

Comment: The developer reports the error still persists after adding the mapping to the sandbox Files/Dirs tab.  Since the data area is on a NAS device, no letter reference exists.  Does this matter?  Does the way the cfc is being called need to be changed? Use a different path reference in the code?

Comment: No, you misunderstood. A mapping will not work in the sandbox. By mapping I am referring to your "popup" mapping in CF. I thought your issue was that you added the mapping "popup" to your sandbox. I was telling you to add the physical path to that directory in the sandbox. Can you not make the NAS device _appear_ as a drive on the server with a drive letter?  I think that is what the CF sandbox needs. I'm not sure if a UNC path will work there.